# stand alone application c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, installation

> So i was wondering if anyone could
>   tell me what would be the best way to
>   go about taking what I've written out
>   in c#(wpf) and turning it into a stand
>   alone application? And if anyone had
>   any links to tutorials or could
>   explain to me how to do so.  Thank you
>   for the assistance.

Let me rephrase. I would like to have my program so that it can run on someone's computer without the need of a IDE, or have have an installation wizard or something along those lines to run the application.

Comment: What... Rephrase your question. If you have written the application just compile it........

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand.  You have a WPF application and you want to make it stand alone?  What do you mean by stand alone?

Comment: What do you mean by "a stand alone application"?

Comment: Where would you like it to stand?  Seriously, it is standalone.  Do you want an installer?

Comment: Do you mean able to run without the framework?

Comment: @rerun: and even without computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the executable of your project. It creates .exe file in side your project folder/bin/Debug/ (or release depend on your build mode). You can copy the .exe file to any machine which has installed the required .net framework and execute it.

Answer (score 4):

I understand that you mean deployment of your application:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969776.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kt85ked.aspx

if that is what you looking for:)